# getting timeout error on dbtransaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-timeout

I am getting a timeout error thrown.  How can I increase the amount of time before the transaction times out?

```
            Database dbSvc = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

            //use one connection
            using (DbConnection conn = dbSvc.CreateConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                DbTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();           
                try
                {
                    ....
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    ret.IsSuccess = false;
                    ret.ExceptionInfo = ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    ret.InvoiceInfo = invoiceOut;
                }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm ALMOST certian that the code you've shown is not `why` you are getting a timeout... what are you doing in the ellipsis part??? lol

Comment: Show your entire method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADO.Net add timeout property to your connection string.  Increase accordingly until it no longer times out, but generally if you are adding a timeout property you should be looking at your db and analyzing weaknesses such as lack of indexes this can be done via analyzing your queries via the sql profilier.